# Comparing values with leading zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that compares two values:

```
} else if (!(parseInt($('#form_value').val()) >= 1)){
    alert("Error: You didn't pick a number!");
```

`form_value` in this case is 001, and I would like to compare it to the one, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried using parseInt but it didn't work either. Any solutions?

Comment: Check what `$('#form_value').val()` returns.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté returns 001

Comment: Define "doesn't work" then. Your posted code is fine. Maybe you can simplify the logic a bit, your posted code is equivalent to `if (+$('#form_value').val() < 1) {`

Comment: I mean, I have an if condition, which checks to see if the form_value if it's not (!) bigger than or equal to 1, then display the error, which is presented after the {. However the form value is 001, and the value I'm comparing it against is 1, so is there a way I can convert the 001?

Comment: Yes, your code looks perfectly fine to me. Maybe it doesn't get to the `else if` part?

Comment: I used the firebug console, and looked at the value being submitted, it's 001, and I am getting that error displayed. @FabrícioMatté

Comment: Well that's weird then. If you're getting the error displayed, then try `else if (!(parseInt($('#form_value').val()) >= 1)){ console.log($('#form_value').val());` the `console.log` there will show the value of the input at the time the check executes on the console.

Comment: 1 is not < to 1. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (!(Number(parseInt($('#form_value').val(),10)) >= 1)){
```

EDIT: try this shortened version:

```
if ( parseInt($('#form_value').val(),10) < 1){
```

Comment: Nope, nothing.. Did you get this solution off of the other post? Because I think that 10 adds 10 to original value.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, yes but paresInt also removes the leading zeros.

Comment: @jeff how does that even relate? The number type does have leading zeroes, only a scalar value.

Comment: @user2738336: That 10 tells JS what base to use.  Without it, JS will guess based on the first characters of the string -- and '0' is the prefix for octal (base 8), which some browsers still understand for some stupid reason.  With the 10, '0' is just a leading zero.

Comment: @cHao Oh you're right - that happens for `parseInt` on older browsers if no radix is specified. The issue does not happen with `Number()` (the [original OP](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18681495/1) code) or `+` implicit coercion though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Number("001");` returns 1 and `Number("000");` returns 0

based on your comment above

> "I'm trying to display an error if the value is less than 1, the
>   lowest value a user can submit is 000 (which is loaded by default), if
>   you pick something, it becomes 001."

If the lowest possible value is 0 then just test for 0...

```
var thing = Number($('#form_Value').val());
if (isNaN(thing) || thing === 0) {
  alert('an error message')'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change the condition to `if ( +( $('#form_value').val() ) < 1 )` or just `if (!+$('#form_value').val())`.

Comment: I'm trying to display an error if the value is less than 1, the lowest value a user can submit is 000 (which is loaded by default), if you pick something, it becomes 001.